# Problem with plotting Taylor polynomials

Tags: plotting, polynomials

I'm trying to plot

```
f1[x_] := Exp[Sin[x]]
```

And its Taylor polynomials

```
taylorFunction1[x_, n_] := Normal[Series[f1[x], { x, 0, n} ] ]
```

for n = 0 to 10, which I've defined as:

```
h1[x_] := taylorFunction1[x, 10]
```

When I plot these on my first interval: [-1/2, 1/2] they both work doing

```
Plot[f1[x], {x, -1/2, 1/2}]

Plot[Evaluate@Normal[{h1[x]}], {x, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

However, when I try:

```
Plot[f1[x], {x, 7/2, 9/2}]
```

I get

[image]

And for some reason with

```
Plot[Evaluate@Normal[{h1[x]}], {x, 7/2, 9/2}]
```

Mathematica returns something bizarre...

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is going on? How do I get the correct plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear[f1, h1, taylorFunction1]

f1[x_] := Exp[Sin[x]]

taylorFunction1[x_Symbol, n_Integer?NonNegative] := 
 Normal[Series[f1[x], {x, 0, n}]]

h1[x_] := taylorFunction1[t, 10] /. t -> x

h1[x]
```

[image]

You need to extend the plot range to see any difference between the plots.

```
Plot[{f1[x], h1[x]}, {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.25, .5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks for the help. I see what you're saying. So is the problem in the input? I come from a programming background, so I figured that that might be it, but I was not sure. Is Mathematica just unwilling to take that literal argument for taylorFunction1?

Comment: To see the problem, change the definition back to `taylorFunction1[x_, n_Integer?NonNegative] := 
 Normal[Series[f1[x], {x, 0, n}]]`; then do `h1[.1] // Trace`

Comment: Oh, nevermind that comment. I notice now the limit you gave 't' in the new definition.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is a limitation of the mathematical approach, not *Mathematica* misbehaving particularly.

The Taylor series centered at $x_0=0$ seems to be divergent outside of $-1<x<1$. Note that Taylor series expansions do not need to converge everywhere in a finite number of terms. You can see evidence in favor of this by trying higher order approximations (starting the series at 0 and `{x, 7/2, 9/2}`, it's obvious that it gets worse).

If you do:

```
h1[x_] = Normal[Series[f1[x], { x, 8/2, 10} ] ]
```

You'll find that the graph for the range `{x, 7/2, 9/2}` is far more accurate (though it will now be equally wrong in the range centered on 0).

One possible solution for using Taylor series approximations for this problem is to manipulate the argument of `h1[x]` so that x will always be within -1 and 1, such as by using the periodicity of `Sin` and the double angle rule modified to account for the exponential.

Comment: that is an excellent point. The root problem was that I wasn't understanding why Mathematica could not plot the Taylor series. However, I realize that my bounds were not great for my problem. You're example is much more insightful

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Pade approximant instead of a Taylor series if you want to have a larger radius of convergence:

```
pade1 = PadeApproximant[Exp[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 5}];
pade2 = PadeApproximant[Exp[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 10}];
```

Here's a comparison:

```
Plot[{pade1, pade2, Exp[Sin[x]]}, {x, -4.5, 4.5}, PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: interesting! I had no knowledge of that function. I'll try it out!